# libFTDI based program does not read properly pin state of FT245

Tags: gcc, compilation, armv7, ftdi

I use Asus router (based on ARMv7 proc) with Advanced Tomato installed
on it as my ARMv7 developer platform. I install compiler (gcc - 5.4.0-1)
plus dependencies and libFTDI (libftdi1 - 1.3-1) from OpenWRT Linux
repo.

I wrote a program on Linux x86_64 platform, using `ftd2xx` library taken from chip manufacturer producer. It works properly. But now I want to port it on ARMv7 platform, using Open Source `libFTDI` library.

I use ft245 chip based board. Pins number 0 to 3 acts as relay outputs while pins 4-7 as optoisolated inputs. My goal is, that running program (named arco) with parameter 0 to 15 turns on/off appropriate relays. Additionally, after such running, program returns actual state of all pins in hex. Running program without parameter, simply returns state of all 8 pins as hex number.
My problem is that when I run program using syntax for example `arco 7` it turn on relays number 0 to 2 and turn off relay number 3. So it is correct. But `ftdi_read_data` returns not actual state of pins but previous. When I run `arco` for the second time (without parameters) it returns correct value.

What I am doing wrong?

Below source of this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ftdi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char c = 0;
    unsigned char pkod = 0;
int     parametr = 0;
int         stat = 0;
int read = 0;
int wyn = 0;
struct ftdi_context ftdic;

    if(argc > 1) { sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &parametr); }
    else { read = 1; }

    if (parametr > 15 || parametr < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr,"Bad call parameter\n");
            exit(1); }

/* Initialize context for subsequent function calls */
ftdi_init(&ftdic);

/* Open FTDI device based on FT245R vendor & product IDs */
if(ftdi_usb_open(&ftdic, 0x5555, 0x0001) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ARCO not avaliable\n");
    exit(2);
}

/* Enable bitbang mode with a single output line */
    ftdi_set_bitmode(&ftdic, 0x0f, BITMODE_BITBANG);

    if(read != 1) {
    pkod=(unsigned char)parametr;
    ftdi_write_data(&ftdic, &pkod, 1);}

    wyn=ftdi_read_data(&ftdic, &c, 1);
    printf ("%x - %d\n",c,wyn);
    exit(stat); 
}
```

UPDATE 1 - small changes in program above

Output from running program twice:

```
root@asus:/opt/static# ./arco 7; arco
f0 - 1
f7 - 1
```

Comment: Is `ftdi_read_data()` returning 1 as expected? Checking for error codes is the _first_ thing you should do. But then, the program here simply returns 0 either way, because `stat` is never updated, and doesn't touch the data which may or may not be in `c` either, so it's clearly not even the actual code you're asking about...

Comment: Yes. `ftdi_read_data()` returning 1 as expected. I changed program to read result of read command (look to the first post, with edited details). Now program returns result and exit code of read command. And look for output from arco 7;arco command. The initial state is `f0` that is inputs in `1` state (because of hardware) and outputs in `0` state.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is `ftdi_read_pins()`. In bitbang mode the pins are sampled regularly and the values held in a FIFO for reading later. If you want to check the current state of the pins you have to bypass that process and that is what the "read pins" call does.